# What does "processor" refer to in the W3C HTML spec?

Tags: html, xml

I quote from W3C:

> All HTML5 and XML processors support UTF-8, UTF-16, Windows-1252, and ISO-8859.

When they say processors do they mean the actual processor or the navigators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "processor" in this context is software which interprets HTML (or XML). It doesn't refer to a CPU (hardware), and applications *other* than web browsers can be (or contain) HTML processors as well. So they're referring to a class of applications which decipher and handle markup, just as a food processor is a category of devices which prepare food items.